# How to handle a SOAP request and send response in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, post, soap

I am having a Rails Application, where I will receive a SOAP request using POST method to it.
I need to handle that request, parse the corresponding XML, and need to respond to that request accordingly.
But, Ruby on Rails by default allows only REST request.

Can anyone please let me know how to handle that in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot avoid requiring soap requests coming into your application (in lieu of say, json) check out the [wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) gem.